# Get number of likes on a facebook page authentication

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

So as of recently, it seems that the graph API call to Facebook for lies, for example:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/pepsi?fields=name,likes

requires authentication.
Now I am reading the docs and can't seem to figure out how to authenticate my server to access this data for a page I'm running.

Do I have to make a Facebook app and link the page to it, and then use the SDK (it is in fact a page about an app), or is there another way that will allow my server to get this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Pages without any restriction (by age or country), you can just use an App Token. Of course you need to create an App to get any Token, but the App Token is easy to generate and valid forever:

```
$app_token = APPID . '|' . APPSECRET;
```

This is how you get the likes with the Token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/pepsi?fields=name,likes&access_token=xxx
```